# Why wont the properties of a custom control show up in the Visual Studio editor?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, visual-studio-2017

No mater what I do I can't seem to get a custom property for my control to show up under the properties menu of the editor. Reading around online it seems like the following should just work, but it does not.

```
public class CustomControl : System.Windows.Forms.Control
{
    public CustomControl() : base()
    {

    }

    [Description("A test property"),
    Category("Appearance"),
    DefaultValue("test"),
    Browsable(true)]
    public string MyCustomProperty { get; set; }
}
```

**Edit**: OK, so I closed and re-opened the project at least three times. Tried compiling the control's assembly separately and then adding it as a reference. All to no avail. Now all of a sudden and for seemingly no reason it has appeared.

Comment: As far as i know they should

Comment: Try cleaning and rebuilding, and restart visual studio if you have to, i remember custom controls being a bit fickle back in the day

Comment: It happens, at times, that removing the control from the Form and adding it back (from the Toolbox) updates the new modifications. If you change properties (add one, refactor another) of a Control, you need to recreate the Control for the changes to appear or be functional. Usually after some heavy editing.

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say "under the properties menu of the editor"? Are you talking about the Visual Studio's Property Window (View | Properties Window {F4})?

Comment: Reading your edit: All is working now?